# how to query partitioned psql in parallel?

Tags: postgresql, psql, amazon-aurora

I have table in aws postgresql, partitioned by `date_col`, but index on `address`.

i have a query to list all items given `address` and `event_name`

it seems that there are no global secondary index, so each query will involves all partitions..

how to improve the query? it is possible to run the query in parallel (by aid of partition keys)? it is possible to do it in [gorm](https://gorm.io/index.html)?

Thanks

eg

The output of `explain select * from tbl where address = '0x5564' and event_name = 'Change';` is

```
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_2016 abl_2  (cost=37.86..41.86 rows=1 width=1087)
        Recheck Cond: (((address)::text = '0x5564'::text) AND ((event_name)::text = 'Change'::text))
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=37.86..37.86 rows=1 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tbl_2016_address_idx  (cost=0.00..4.06 rows=227 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((address)::text = '0x5564'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on abl_2016_event_decoded_idx  (cost=0.00..33.79 rows=8874 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((event)::text = 'Change'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_2017_01_01 tbl_3  (cost=4.01..11.80 rows=1 width=906)
        Recheck Cond: ((address)::text = '0x5564'::text)
        Filter: ((event)::text = 'Change'::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tbl_2017_01_01_address_idx  (cost=0.00..4.01 rows=2 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((address)::text = '0x5564'::text)
  ->  Index Scan using tbl_2017_01_02_address_idx on tbl_2017_01_02 logs_4  (cost=0.01..8.01 rows=1 width=913)
        Index Cond: ((address)::text = '0x5564'::text)
        Filter: ((event)::text = 'Change'::text)
...
```

from the explain plan, it seems that the query is querying all partitions, but trying to use the indexes on each partition...

my question, it is possible to make the query run in parellel by aid of partitions. should i do it manually in gorm?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on your data, configuration and query. Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this query, the query itself and the ddl for all tables and indexes involved? All in plain text, as an update to your original question. Without it, it's impossible to answer your question, but you could read the manual.

Comment: You didn't show the query, nor the ddl, nor the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)`. But the answer to your question is Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Thanks. Any existing solution or lib to do it in go? or i have to do it manually myself?

Comment: PostgreSQL will use parallel query automatically if the partitions are big enough or numerous enough to warrant that. PostgreSQL can use different parallel workers each partition, but normally it will use a parallel scan on each partition. Note that a plain `SELECT * FROM` will rarely use parallel query because of the many rows that need to be exchanged.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. I am a little confused by `a plain SELECT * FROM will rarely use parallel query because of the many rows that need to be exchanged`. the plain select statement can scan each partition and then put the results together.... why plain SELECT rarely use parallel query?

How to make the select query parallel?

Comment: All result rows are eventually gathered at the original backend to deliver to the client. Exchanging rows between worker processes is expensive, so if many rows have to be exchanged, that ruins the benefit of parallelization.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel query and partitioning are pretty much unrelated. In fact the partitioning will probably make parallel query less effective. If you want to encourage parallel query, you could set parallel_*_cost to zero.  Of course doing that will encourage parallel query even when it is counterproductive.

If you want to get multiple page reads happening at the same time, increasing effective_io_concurrency might be a better bet.